# Unexported object imported by a ':::' call: 'tsfeatures:::scalets'

Tags: r, package

After doing devtools::check(cran=TRUE)
I got this warning.
I saw others say we cannot use ":::" on CRAN.
So, how to fix this problem? Thank you for helping!

```
> checking dependencies in R code ... NOTE
  Unexported object imported by a ':::' call: 'tsfeatures:::scalets'
    See the note in ?`:::` about the use of this operator.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you could find the answer.
https://github.com/drsimonj/twidlr/issues/16

Summing up there are many options:

- Contact package authors and ask them to export the relevant function.
- Copy the function source code and cite the author appropriately. Use roxygen2 @references or manually \references in man file. In my opinion reference at the level of function is satisfactory if this function is one of many in your package. Remember that the specific function might depends on many others from the package, so then a lot of code have to be copied.
- Another trick is using getFromNamespace() `fun <- utils::getFromNamespace("fun", "pkg")`. When you building a package the order and place of functions is not relevant (unless you use S4 or other exotic objects).

Comment: Thank you for reply. Would you mind explain a bit more detail about how to do make each method applicable? I want to use method 2 or 3. But not sure where should I cite the author (in Description or R code part). For Method 3, should I add getFromNamespace() before the function I built? Thanks

Comment: Hey, when I use ```tsfeatures<-utils::getFromNamespace("tsfeatures", "scalets")``` before my function, the error said "Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘scalets’"

Comment: You have to remember to update the DESCRIPTION file in Imports section with scalets package.

Comment: For method 2, is that means. I copy that specific function code from other's package and then comment a reference about author. But if I do that and do not use ":::" anymore, there are more error comes out.

Comment: From method 3, the error I get said                                                                               ``` Error in utils::getFromNamespace("tsfeatures") : environment specified is not a package```

Comment: Solution 2 demanding to import all necessary packages which are used by the scalets there. For the 3th use tsfeatures<-utils::getFromNamespace("tsfeatures", "scalets") although add scalets to your imports in Description file.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar case, where I wanted to use non-exported functions from the `cli` package (see simplified sample code below). What I did was to change the function environment to the `cli` namespace. As a result, my function has direct access to the `cli` internals. The code passes `R CMD CHECK`.

NB: Of course this approach only makes sense, if your function is strongly coupled with the other package, here `cli`.

```
# code adapted from cli_line but without the automatic linebreak
cli_cat <- function(..., col = NULL, background_col = NULL, file = stdout()) {
  out <- paste0(..., collapse = "\n")
  out <- apply_style(out, col)
  out <- apply_style(out, background_col, bg = TRUE)
  cat(out, sep = "", file = file, append = TRUE)
}
environment(cli_cat) <- asNamespace("cli")  # to access internal cli functions


cli_cat("hello", col="grey")
```